# Summoning Written Books and others

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using the /summon command, is it possible to summon *written* books? I have the /give command for the book that I wrote (can supply said command if needed), but when I tried changing it to be in the /summon format, it summoned a piece of stone. Another quick question I had along the same lines is summoning enchanted items. Any suggestions?

This is another book with the same number of pages and the same characteristics as my first book (click event, colored text)

```
/give @p written_book 1 0 {pages:["{\"text\":\"Welcome\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}","{\"text\":\"Introduction\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}","{\"text\":\"DRAMA!\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}","[\"\",{\"text\":\"C\",\"color\":\"dark_red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/say Test Success\"}},{\"text\":\"lIcK MURdEr!\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}]","{\"text\":\"Dramatic ending!\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}"],title:"How to Kill a Minecrafter",author:SMILIECHICKEN,generation:3}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to summon them and not just use the /give command?

Comment: Can you provide the commands you tried using?

Comment: @Jason_ Not really, but I have had this question for a while, and it looks good.

Comment: @Skylinerw The book I wrote is pretty long, so I'll put up another book with the same number of pages and the same characteristics (click event, colored text.) I'll put in the answer section, since it's too long to fill here. It's in /give form now, but I need in it summon -- if that's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. You can use the datatag like this:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:written_book",count:1,Damage:0,tag:{pages:[I don't want to copy-paste]}}}
```