# How to /give a written book in Minecraft Java 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'd like to give a player a written book, but I keep getting "invalid book tag" whenever I actually open the book. The wiki says to use a "serialized JSON object or an array of strings and/or objects (see [Commands#Raw JSON text](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text)) or an unescaped string". I looked at the link but couldn't make much sense of it, so if anyone could give an explanation of what that means that would be extremely helpful. Things I've tried:

```
/give @p minecraft:written_book{title:"Magick Moste Evile1",author:"Herobrine",generation:0,Pages:["{\"text\":\"Testing\"}"]} 1
/give @p minecraft:written_book{title:"Magick Moste Evile2",author:"Herobrine",generation:0,Pages:[{"testing"}]} 1
/give @p minecraft:written_book{title:"Magick Moste Evile3",author:"Herobrine",generation:0,Pages:["testing"]} 1
/give @p minecraft:written_book{title:"Magick Moste Evile4",author:"Herobrine",generation:0,Pages:[{"{\"text\":\"Testing\"}"}]} 1
```

Some of them don't actually run without errors in the command chat, while others give me a book but the inside just has the "invalid book tag" error message. I've looked at other questions on this site and others, like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261412/summoning-written-books-and-others) one, but they're all for old versions and don't work when I try to update them to 1.14. What is the correct format for the pages of a written book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it: the first one was correct except the `pages` nbt needs to be lowercase and needs to be the first nbt tag listed:

```
give @p written_book{pages:["[\"\",{\"text\":\"The art of rituals is of vital importance to the player.\"}]","{\"text\":\" It is a matter of life and death,\\na road either to safety or to ruin.\"}]","{\"text\":\"Hence it is a subject of inquiry which can on no account be neglected.\"}"title:"Magick Moste Evile",author:Herobrine,display:{Lore:["Of the Horcrux, wickedest of magical inventions, we shall not speak nor give direction —"]}}
```

Comment: to make this a little more expressive, Id suggest adding the correct version to your answer to help those who are more visual learners.